# How can I convert ePub files to RTF format?

Tags: conversion, rtf, epub

I want to convert a text in **.epub format to .rtf** format.

How can I do it?

Even when preserving images is preferred, .epub files are often composed only of text, so any methods that ignore images could be all right too.

Comment: You would have to look up information about the respective formats of [ePub](http://idpf.org/epub) and [RTF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725), both of which are publicly documented. Or, you could use a program whose author has already done so, such as [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with converting e-book formats using [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/). This is an e-book library platform that also contains a built-in converter. Generally I've used it to convert PDF/RTF files to EPUB but the other way around works as well. Overall I've found it to be quite intelligent and tweakable.

To convert your file, you first have to load it into Calibre using the "Add book" functionality. Then, select the book and click "Convert books". You select the input format on the top left and the desired output format on the top right.

Comment: I like Calibre, too, but wouldn't offer it as an answer here, as that sorta points to a more appropriate stack being [Softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @JeffZeitlin , I think there is no need to open another equivalent question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . The question requested just any method to solve a job. If Calibre is the correct answer, it is OK for me. However, I think it would be proper to wait for confirmation to upvote this answer (a single "should work" is not enough for me).

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - Not suggesting that the parallel question should be opened; just that if the querent is more interested in what software exists to do it, it would be more appropriate to migrate it. Since it's not _clear_ that that's the case, I'm not proposing that it be, just noting that requests for software recommendations are considered off-topic for this stack.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - That concern about topicality is why I didn't _answer_ the question, but merely commented on it.

Comment: Well, @JeffZeitlin, I would prefer for the rules to solve this matter, and set clear how to proceed in this cases.